# How do I do this with Emeditor or any text editing tool

Tags: text, edit, emeditor

I have 2 text files.

The first one has letters like this:

```
Message1:A

Message2:B

Message3:C

Message4:D

Message5:E
```

....

The second text file has letter like this:

```
D:Answer4

A:Answer1

E:Answer5

C:Answer3

B:Answer2
```

...

I want to match 2 of them so I can get the result:

```
Message1:Answer1

Message2:Answer2

Message3:Answer3

Message4:Answer4

Message5:Answer5
```

...

Please note that sorting them A-Z , Z-A, 1-9 , long-short , short-long is not allowed (Any kinds of sorting)
The 2 text files are randomized before editing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use EmEditor, you can use the **Join CSV** feature of EmEditor.

1. Go to the **Tools** menu, select **Customize**, **CSV** page, click **Add** button to define a *Colon* format: 
   Enter "Colon separated" in the **CSV Formats** list.
   Enter "Colon" to the **Toolbar button title**.
   Enter `:` (a colon) to the **Delimiter**.
   Disable **Allow delimiters in double quotes**.

[image: Customize dialog- CSV page]

2. Open your first text file, and click the **Colon** format in the **CSV/Sort** toolbar. Do the same with the second file.
3. Click **Join CSV** button in the **CSV/Sort** toolbar.

[image: CSV/Sort toolbar]

4. In the **Join CSV** dialog box, select options exactly as shown in the screenshot. Click the **Join Now** button.

[image: Join CSV dialog]

5. A new document will be created with the expected results.

[image: Results]

Comment: Thank you God, been struggling with this for so long! Thank you for helping me